# Скрипт для поиска файла по шаблону

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os, fnmatch

dirpath = input('Путь к каталогу: ')
while not os.path.isdir(dirpath): #проверка пути
    print('Такого каталога нет')
    dirpath = input('Путь к каталогу: ')

filename = input('Имя файла: ')

path_f = []
for d,dirs,files in os.walk(dirpath):
    for f in files:
        if fnmatch(f, filename):
            path = (os.path.join(d, f))
            path_f.append(path)
```

Программа выдаёт:

> ```
> if fnmatch(f, filename):
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Если вам дан верный ответ, принято отмечать его правильным, чтоб остальным было сразу ясно, что проблема решена и никаких дополнительных уточнений/ответов не нужно.

Answer (score 5):

Вы импортируете модуль `fnmatch` и пытаетесь использовать его как функцию.

Вам нужно либо импортировать из модуля `fnmatch` именно функцию `fnmatch` вот так:

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch
```

Либо, оставив такой импорт, как у вас есть, использовать полное имя функции:

```
...
if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, filename):
    ...
```

Comment: или [использовать `matched = fnmatch.filter(files, filename)`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437452/23044).