# Как реализовать поиск по массиву?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как реализовать поиск по массиву? Массив - это папки, которые сканируются.

```
import os, fnmatch

dirpath = input('Путь к каталогу: ')
while not os.path.isdir(dirpath): #проверка пути
    print('Такого каталога нет')
    dirpath = input('Путь к каталогу: ')

filename = input('Имя файла: ')

path_f = []
for d,dirs,files in os.walk(dirpath):
    for f in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, filename):
            path = (os.path.join(d, f))
            print (path)
```

Необходимость в массиве возникла ввиду того, что некоторые папки скрипт не сканирует.

Comment: Не могли бы вы подробнее пояснить, какие папки скрипт не сканирует, и как поиск по массиву предположительно может этому помочь? Из вашего вопроса не особенно понятно, чего же вы на самом деле хотите.

Comment: Не сканирует system32, но у других сканирует, думаю сначала скрипт пройдёт по папкам зафиксирует их вложения, и запишет, жто всё как массив данных, а потом уже программа благополучно пройдёться по массиву. 

import os
os.listdir('C:/Windows/system32') - тут отображает их значение.

Comment: Покажите, как вы запускаете так, что не сканирует `system32`? Вы понимаете, что если не сканирует, то не будет этого делать и тогда, когда вместо того, чтобы выводить данные сразу, вы будете записывать их в массив?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s68664f2mlslh1e/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9.png?dl=0

Comment: заголовок вопроса не соответствует содержимому. Так как уже дан ответ, который отвечает на вопрос в заголовке, то лучше отдельный вопрос задать: "Почему создаётся впечатление, что `os.walk('C:/')`  не заходит в `system32` папку?"

Answer (score 1):

Если `filename` это буквальное имя файла, то чтобы узнать есть ли оно в списке `files` (c учётом регистра) не нужен `fnmatch` -- достаточно `filename in files`:

```
for root, _, files in os.walk(dirpath):
    if filename in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Если `filename` это некоторый файловый шаблон, например, `'*host?'` и/или необходимо сравнение без учёта регистра на данной ОСи, то можно [`fnmatch.filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) использовать:

```
for root, _, files in os.walk(dirpath):
    matched = fnmatch.filter(files, filename)
    if matched: # occurs at least once
        print("\n".join([os.path.join(root, f) for f in matched]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый нажёжный и быстрый способ - это использовать метод index, он возвращает индекс первого совпадения.

Из документации:

```
[66.25, 333, -1, 333, 1, 1234.5, 333]
a.index(333)
1
```

https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html